# CiviEvent sends an invoice copy to every guest

Tags: civievent, invoice

For a paid event set up in Civi 5.10.3 to allow 'Register multiple participants?', every person registered gets a PDF copy of the invoice with their registration confirmation if an email address is supplied.

I can't think of any good reason for this, particularly as the default, as it usually leads to confusion.

Is there any way to suppress this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a slightly different profile for the 'lead' person to register vs subsequent participant registrations, in order to identify who should receive the invoice, and then use Civi Rules to send the email /PDF?

This is either instead of the usual receipt email, or as well but that doesn't include the invoice and serves only to confirm the booking for that individual.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to respond. Seems a possible solution, but I haven't been able to get Civi Rules to install…

Comment: Are you getting error messages when installing? If you're using CiviRules to send emails, you'll need both the https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules extension and the https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api extension

Comment: Oops, I was about to write "CiviRules installs successfully, but doesn't produce a menu", but taking a fresh look I see it's within the admin menu, not on the menu bar as the docs illustrate.

Comment: @jaapjansma it might be worth updating the screenshots for CiviRules?