# Civi Event Invoice goes to everyone - I only want it to go to the first person

Tags: civievent, invoice

Is there any way that I can have automated invoices going only to the person who's registering multiple contacts rather than every contact email?  We allow multiple registrations and one person will pay (the first person registered).  with the confirmation, which we do want everyone to get, they are also all getting a copy of the invoice receipt which we only want to go to the person registering everyone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Civi Sends emails and receipts to all the participant registrants by default. To avoid sending invoice will need bit of custom coding.

Comment: Would this be a straight forward ask of our developer or is it something I could do?

Comment: You can implement altermailparams hook via an extension and unset the attachments with some logics

Comment: see also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/civievent-sends-an-invoice-copy-to-every-guest